# page not found error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have anchor in header.php as below:

```
<a href="<?php base_url();>backend">Backend</a>
```

Also have the controller named backend.php in Controllers folder.

I also routed this code in routes.php file like

```
$route('default_controller')='frontend';
$route('backend')='backend';
```

Backend controller page is:

```
<?php 
class Backend extends CI_Controller { 
          public function __construct(){ 
                  parent::__construct(); 
         } 
         public function index(){ 
             $data['title'] = 'Backend Page'; 
             $this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
             $this->load->view('backend/reg', $data); 
             $this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
       } 
}
```

Although getting error 404 Page not found.

Comment: could you post your controller code and more details like the link that is beeing generated?

Comment: <?php
class Backend extends CI_Controller {
 public function __construct(){
  parent::__construct();
 }
 public function index(){
  $data['title'] = 'Backend Page';
  $this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
  $this->load->view('backend/reg', $data);
  $this->load->view('templates/footer');
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure all controller and models etc **Ucfirst** example Frontend.php instead of frontend.php

Codeigniter Docs http://www.codeigniter.com/docs

Auto load **url helper in application.config/autoload.php**

Change route from

`$route('default_controller') ='frontend';`

to

`$route['default_controller'] = "frontend";`

`$route['backend'] = "backend";`

I you have not set up you config to remove index.php with htaccess then use index.php in link.

`<a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/backend');">Backend</a>`

**Example controllers/Backend.php**

```
<?php 

class Backend extends CI_Controller { 
public function __construct(){ 
parent::__construct(); 
} 
public function index(){ 
$data['title'] = 'Backend Page'; 
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
$this->load->view('backend/reg', $data); 
$this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
} 
}
```

**Example controllers/Frontend.php**

```
<?php 

class Frontend extends CI_Controller { 
public function __construct(){ 
parent::__construct(); 
} 
public function index(){ 
$data['title'] = 'Frontend Page'; 
$this->load->view('templates/header', $data); 
$this->load->view('frontend/reg', $data); 
$this->load->view('templates/footer'); 
} 
}
```

Link here for htaccess examples for removing index.php on windows os https://github.com/riwakawebsitedesigns/htaccess_for_codeigniter

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<a href = "<?php echo base_url();?>/pathforyourbackend">Backend </a> // include also the folder where your backend file is stored
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: How can i define a controller in autoload.php file? I think , its for model, helper.

Comment: oh,,sorry its in your config.php ,, do something like this  $config['base_url'] = "http://localhost/path"